Duffing Equation:Transition to Chaos
I create the following code  but the results were not that I expected for. The paper I study is  Duffing Equation
My code gives me the following. But I want a smoother and clearer plot. What should I change?
(* Define parameters for the Duffing oscillator *)
delta = 0.1;
alpha = -1;
beta = 1;
gamma = 0.338;  (* Increased driving force *)
omega = 1.4;
tmax = 2000;  (* Extended time range up to 2000 *)

(* Define the system of ODEs with a smaller step size *)
duffingGeneral = {
   x'[t] == v[t],
   v'[t] == -delta v[t] - alpha x[t] - beta x[t]^3 + gamma Cos[omega t],
   x[0] == 1,  (* Initial conditions *)
   v[0] == 1
};

(* Solve the system over time with a refined step size *)
solutionGeneral = NDSolveValue[duffingGeneral, {x, v}, {t, 0, tmax}, 
   MaxStepSize -> 0.05];

(* Full phase portrait plot with enhanced resolution *)
fullPhasePortrait = ParametricPlot[
  Evaluate[{solutionGeneral[[1]][t], solutionGeneral[[2]][t]}],
  {t, 0, tmax},
  PlotLabel -> "Full Phase Portrait for \[Gamma] = 0.338, \[Alpha] = -1, \[Omega] = 1.4",
  AxesLabel -> {"x(t)", "v(t)"},
  PlotRange -> All,
  GridLines -> Automatic,
  AspectRatio -> 1,
  PlotStyle -> {Blue, Thick},
  PlotPoints -> 1000
];

(* Tail phase portrait plot, zoomed into the end behavior *)
tailPhasePortrait = ParametricPlot[
  Evaluate[{solutionGeneral[[1]][t], solutionGeneral[[2]][t]}],
  {t, 1980, tmax},  (* Focus on the last 20 time units *)
  PlotLabel -> "Tail Phase Portrait for \[Gamma] = 0.338, \[Alpha] = -1, \[Omega] = 1.4 (t \[Element] [1980, 2000])",
  AxesLabel -> {"x(t)", "v(t)"},
  PlotRange -> All,
  GridLines -> Automatic,
  AspectRatio -> 1,
  PlotStyle -> {Blue, Thick},
  PlotPoints -> 1000
];

(* Display both plots side by side *)
GraphicsGrid[{{fullPhasePortrait, tailPhasePortrait}}]


The plots that I need are the following


I don't know if something like this will help you: Duffing

Hello @E.Chan-López. How did you create that?

The idea is to change the initial condition. The solution at the origin instead of $(x_0,v_0)=(1,1)$, but in a certain interval. Your modified code looks like this:
(*Define parameters for the Duffing oscillator*)
delta = 0.1;
alpha = -1;
beta = 1;
gamma = 0.338;  (*Increased driving force*)
omega = 1.4;
tmax = 2000;  (*Extended time range up to 2000*)

(*Define the system of ODEs with a smaller step size*)
duffingGeneral = {x'[t] == v[t], 
   v'[t] == -delta  v[t] - alpha  x[t] - beta  x[t]^3 + 
     gamma  Cos[omega  t], x[0] == 0,(*Initial conditions*)v[0] == 0};

(*Solve the system over time with a refined step size*)
solutionGeneral = 
  NDSolveValue[duffingGeneral, {x, v}, {t, 0, tmax}, 
   MaxStepSize -> 0.05];

(*Full phase portrait plot with enhanced resolution*)
fullPhasePortrait = 
  ParametricPlot[
   Evaluate[{solutionGeneral[[1]][t], solutionGeneral[[2]][t]}], {t, 
    700, 998}, 
   PlotLabel -> 
    "Segment Phase Portrait for \[Gamma] = 0.338, \[Alpha] = -1, \
\[Omega] = 1.4 (t \[Element] [700, 998])", 
   AxesLabel -> {"x(t)", "v(t)"}, PlotRange -> All, 
   GridLines -> Automatic, AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio, 
   PlotStyle -> {Blue, Thickness[0.002]}, PlotPoints -> 1000];

(*Tail phase portrait plot,zoomed into the end behavior*)
tailPhasePortrait = 
  ParametricPlot[
   Evaluate[{solutionGeneral[[1]][t], solutionGeneral[[2]][t]}], {t, 
    1980, tmax},(*Focus on the last 20 time units*)
   PlotLabel -> 
    "Tail Phase Portrait for \[Gamma] = 0.338, \[Alpha] = -1, \
\[Omega] = 1.4 (t \[Element] [1980, 2000])", 
   AxesLabel -> {"x(t)", "v(t)"}, PlotRange -> All, 
   GridLines -> Automatic, AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio, 
   PlotStyle -> {Blue, Thickness[0.002]}, PlotPoints -> 1000, 
   ImageSize -> 550];

(*Display both plots side by side*)
GraphicsGrid[{{fullPhasePortrait, tailPhasePortrait}}, ImageSize -> 850]



First of all, thank you for your response. But I have a question, when I tried it on Online Mathematica did not give the same results

I've always had my doubts about using the cloud, as I sometimes encounter problems like the one you mention. Something that I can run on a notebook is not the same in the cloud.

I see. Usually I write code on my laptop but now I am out of the office, for this reason and tried cloud. I will not trust it again

I guess there is still a lot of development to be done in the cloud, so we'd better rely on the desktop version. Regards, Athanasios!
